# Translate "appendices" from \addappheadtotoc in other languages with polyglossia

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, polyglossia

How can I translate "appendices" in Italian?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
dummy text
\chapter{My second chapter}
dummy text

\appendix
\addappheadtotoc
\chapter{my appendix}
\end{document}
```

Also, why is the page number of "Appendices" 3 and not 4? Is it possible to remove the page number shown for "Appendices" from the Toc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `appendix` package doesn't define any localized string; one has to add

```
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{<Appendices>}
```

to the appropriate language set; for Italian it should be

```
\addto\captionsitalian{%
   \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendici}%
   \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendici}%
}
```

(the same for both `babel` and `polyglossia`). This doesn't solve the problem with the page number, though.

You can actually dispense from the `appendix` package for this.

Just do

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Appendici}{}{}}%
}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

Full example

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % use it or not as you please

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Appendici}{}{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}           
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
dummy text
\chapter{My second chapter}
dummy text

\appendix
\chapter{my appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better version when `hyperref` is used:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}

\usepackage{hyperref}                              

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \hypertarget{appendixstart}{}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{
    \protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\hyperlink{appendixstart}{Appendici}}{}{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{My first chapter}
dummy text
\chapter{My second chapter}
dummy text

\appendix
\chapter{my appendix}
\end{document}
```

This will turn also “Appendici” in the table of contents into a link to the first page of the appendix.

Comment: Amazing stuff!!