# captionsgreek doesn't work

Tags: appendices, thesis, appendix

I'm writing my thesis in LaTeX and I'm trying to put an Appendix in it. I want the Appendix's title to be in Greek, so [as stated here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202512/translate-appendices-from-addappheadtotoc-in-other-languages-with-polyglossia) with the `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}`, I can use the following:

```latex
\addto\captionsgreek{%
   \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Παράρτημα}%
   \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Παράρτημα}%
}
```

But my problem is that TeXStudio doesn't recognize the `\captionsgreek` command even though I put the babel package. I am a new user, so I can't figure where I'm wrong. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If in your real document, you have `{% \renewcommand …`, be aware that the end of the line is not read, since  `%` makes the rest of the line a comment in the code. Also, it's not TeX Studio which is responsible for this, it is the compiler. TeX Studio is just a specialised editor.

Comment: I used this before the \begin{document}. So, should i put it without the percentage % sign? @Bernard

Comment: Also, the problem is in the captionsgreek command, should it be recognised by the babel package or should i put another one?

Comment: If you look at  `greek.ldf`, you have this definition: `\def\appendixname{\textPi\textalpha\textrho\acctonos\textalpha\textrho
    \texttau\texteta\textmu\textalpha}%`, perhaps you should do the same for \appendixtocname: `\addtocaptionsgreek{\appendixtocname}{...}`. Or maybe \addtocaptionsgreek{\appendixtocname}{\appendixname} or, even simpler \let\appendixtocname=\\appendixname (not tested, but it's worth trying).

Comment: What do you mean with “TeXStudio doesn't recognize `\captionsgreek`”? Do you get errors when running LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, i get some errors. @egreg

Comment: Could you copy and paste those errors?